# Auto clicker with Ui Regoniser

Tags: button, regression, artificial-intelligence, helper, auto

please I hope I can find someone help me as I'm not good in programming

all I want android app helps me to press or swipe random button appear on screen which I took screenshots of it so when the app see on the screen no.1 picture press it immediately and no.2 picture swipe it  immediately also , and those are  appear at randomly places in the screen .

I tried many apps but it press at the place i point it in not regencies the screen and tap where that picture appear

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.